# Where to host Meteor-Apps?

Tags: heroku, meteor, hosting

I want to build a Meteor-App to run a little side-project/business. This in mind:

1. I want a cheap environment (online) to test and share my progress
2. I want to have the option to scale it up in terms of production in a few months
3. I want to use some standard command line tools to push to this service
4. The database options have also to scale up if i need more

I've started looking into [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), but are there any "good practices" which anybody can recommend? I never hosted a Meteor-App, and **i want to avoid a private server** because of administration etc.

Comment: Hosting on Heroku is pretty easy, the only thing you'll need is a proper buildpack, [there are a few for different needs](https://www.google.pl/search?q=heroku+meteor+buildpack). That said, you should avoid asking [opinion-based questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I have a different opinion on your opinion-thinking, but thanks for the link!

Comment: Of course, there's also Meteor’s free servers that you get via [`meteor deploy`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteordeploy). They don’t give you any options to scale up, however, but seeing as it’s free it’s a good place to test in the very early stages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meteor apps are immediately ready to deploy to Heroku. Your question is very broad, but Heroku fits the bill for every parameter you specified.

Here's a flow for creating an example meteor app and deploying it:

```
$ meteor create --example leaderboard
$ cd leaderboard
$ git init . && git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: These steps are not sufficient, at least for Meteor 0.8.2.  See my answer below.

Comment: @DejayClayton where's your answer?

Comment: Looks like it is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117965/how-to-deploy-meteor-0-6-0-to-heroku/24706472#24706472

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options:

- [Meteor.Com](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Category:Meteor.Com) -- the easiest option, free hosting from Meteor. Super easy deployments, but limited resources until the Galaxy platform is complete. Not suitable for very high load/traffic sites (yet).
- [PaaS providers](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Category:PaaS_providers) -- cloud hosting where you are responsible for your app, and the provider manages the infrastructure for you. Generally small virtual machines which host node apps, with great deployment tools.
- [Own Infrastructure](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Category:Own_Infrastructure) -- info on how to host on your own servers, or via IaaS providers like Amazon AWS, Digital Ocean, Rackspace, etc. Most complicated option.
- [Deployment Services](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Category:Deployment_Services) - services to manage deployment to your own servers (or IaaS servers). Advantages of the above but with the management taken care of for you (managed deployment, monitoring, etc).

Source: [Meteorpedia](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Category:Deployment)

Answer (score 1):

I have been hosting some meteor apps on [Webfactions](https://www.webfaction.com) and it has been working fine so far.

Here is a tutorial : 
http://racingtadpole.com/blog/meteor-mongodb-webfaction/